# What are the possible types in the Google Calendar API events/watch request body?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am experimenting with the Goole Calendar API in Postman and trying to be able to watch events. My problem is that the documentation at https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch mentions that the request body has a type property of type string that is "The type of delivery mechanism used for this channel." It does not, however, mention what the various options are. The `watch` section also does not have on of the API explorers attached to it so I can't use the popup that would be there to figure out the options.

Does anyone know what the various options are? Is there some part of the documentation that I am missing?

The address property is also a bit vague, but I'm fairly certain it needs to be a URL.

Comment: You can try using the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), pretty much as you would use the API explorer. Have you tried it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use type="web_hook". I left feedback in the documentation to fix this. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! A colleague pointed me to the documentation that had that answer as well. Now I just have to figure out how to get the callback URL to be allowed…